# Repeatable counter for Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I've been looking for a repeatable countdown timer for joomla 3.x for quite a while now. By repeatable, I mean that I can set the day of the week, and the timer just does its thing. Let's say that I have an event every Saturday. I need the module or plugin to display the timer with time left. Once time's up, it counts down until the next Saturday. If the extension is 2.5, but it works with 3.x, I'll still use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the [Countdown](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/countdown) category on JED. If there is nothing there that suits your needs, you might need to look into developing your own module.

Comment: @Lodder. Thanks for the reply. I've searched through these before, but none seems to offer the option to repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself in the very same situation and none of the published modules on the JED did the trick. So I created a very basic module that will do just this: it uses a DateInterval, so you can write "next thursday at 3:30 pm" and it will parse it!

http://www.fasterjoomla.com/repository/mod-rixx-countdown/mod-rixx-countdown-0-1

It ships with two views (one full which shows all available fields, one for days only), it's plain-text no fancy graphics. I used it in a module position inlined in an article.

Comment: Before I accept this great module as the answer, do you have the full view version? Right now, I'm using the OSTimer module, and it counts down even with the second. Something like the OSTimer but with your functionality would be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: So I'm modifying the OSTimer module to make it repeatable. This seems way easier than trying to write one from scratch. Once done, are you interested in using?

Comment: The full view is already installed, simply open the advanced tab and choose the layout named "full"